# Woocommerce custom product search in product category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am using a custom woocommerce product search in my wordpress site where it searchs only in product titles. I would like to include the search in category names too. So if someone search a text, and if that's exists in product category name, all those products under that category also need to be listed.

Here is code I am using:

```
function wc_filter_search_by_title_only( $search, &$wp_query ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $not_allowed_post_types = apply_filters( 'wc_filter_search_not_allowed_array', array(
        'product', //Default WooCommerce products post type
        'shop_webhook', //MyStyle Custom post type
    ) );

    if ( empty( $search ) || ! in_array( $wp_query->query_vars['post_type'], $not_allowed_post_types ) ) {
        return $search; // skip processing - no search term in query
    }

    $q = $wp_query->query_vars;
    $n = ! empty( $q['exact'] ) ? '' : '%';

    $search =
    $searchand = '';

    foreach ( (array) $q['search_terms'] as $term ) {
        $term = esc_sql( $wpdb->esc_like( $term ) );
        $search .= "{$searchand}($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}')";
        $searchand = ' AND ';
    }

    if ( ! empty( $search ) ) {
        $search = " AND ({$search}) ";
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
            $search .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_password = '') ";
    }

    return $search;
}
add_filter( 'posts_search', 'wc_filter_search_by_title_only', 500, 2 );
```

Kindly let me know if anyway I can implement this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way really is to use [SearchWP](https://searchwp.com/) with its [WooCommerce extension](https://searchwp.com/extensions/woocommerce-integration/). Besides, it gives you a lot more functionality than just that.